# Como simular onclick checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-datatables

Bom dia Pessoal, eu possuo um formulario que é uma datatable, e tenho um botão que marca ou desmarca, todas as checkboxs dessa datatable, por padrão esses checkbox vem marcado, eu preciso que ao ler a página ou ao clicar no botão marcar todas o checkbox altere sua propriedade simulando um click em cada checkbox. segue abaixo meu botão. Tem como?

function marcardesmarcar() {

```
$('.marcar').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) 
       $(this).attr("checked", false);
    else 
       $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal depois de muito estudar, consegui resolver utilizando a função abaixo.

function marcardesmarcar() {

```
$('.marcar').on('click', function () {
    if (this.checked) 
       $(this).attr("checked", false);
    else 
       $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
// Chama a função de clique através do trigger
$('.marcar').trigger('click');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      toggleCheckBoxs(); // inicia alternando os checks boxs
    });


    function toggleCheckBoxs(){
      var checks = $('input');
      // checks.map((i,x) => x.checked = !x.checked );
      checks.map((i,x) => $(x).click() ); // aqui dispara o evento de click
    }
```

Verifica aqui: [teste](https://plnkr.co/edit/rRHefUR74E1rm5VaSOHJ?p=preview)

Comment: essa funçao que uso ja faz da mesma forma que a sua, minha duvida é se a sua resposta vai simular o evento click, nos checksboxs

Comment: hum, entendi, atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar desta forma, automaticamente ao marcar o seu `CheckBox`, ele busca todos os outros e marca o mesmo valor do seu `checkbox` clicado:

```js
$("#marcar").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: não da assim, porque eu preciso percorrer o datatable, $('.marcar').each(function (), .marcar eu uso a classe

Comment: E por que você usa `.prop()` em um if e no else você usa o  `.attr()`?

Comment: desculpa estava testando e esqueci de inverter,

Answer (score 0):

Posso te ajudar mostrando como você pode fazer isso com JS Vanilla:

```
// Pega todos os elementos com a class .marcar
const marcar = document.querySelectorAll('.marcar')

//Transforma a HTMLCollection em array e intera cada item
Array.from(marcar).forEach(el => {
  // Checa o valor de cada elemento
  let isChecked = el.checked
  return el.checked = !isChecked // Seta o atributo inverso do que está atual
})
```

Comment: vou dar uma pesquisada em JS Vanilla...

Comment: Mas isso resolve seu problema?